# Changing my hosts file won't work

Tags: networking, hosts

A while ago, I messed with my hosts file and it worked just fine. Then I wanted to undo my changes, so instead of deleting the entries, I completely restored the hosts file using one of Microsoft's quick fix download things.

Then I tried looking up a solution on the web, one of them suggested that I make a whole new hosts file and save it in the System32/drivers/etc directory. Now it's a "Text Document" instead of a "File" like the other files in that directory.

Any changes I make now do not work. I tried it on a family member's computer, and it worked fine, so it definitely has to do with the  mess-up on my part. Just for clarification: My hosts file has worked in the past. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Change the file extension.

Comment: @Ramhound: That should be an answer :)

Comment: Change it to what?

Comment: Nothing.. The host file doesn't have a file extension normally

Comment: I can't? Maybe I'm skipping a step here?

Comment: In Windows explorer > Folder options, make sure "Hide extensions of known file type" is unchecked. Rename - delete the "txt" extension of the host file but make sure the original Host file does not exist (is deleted)

Comment: I don't see a checkbox for that.

Comment: @user293535 - If you don't see file extensions then you have the option to hide them enabled.  Keep looking.

Comment: This question should be closed as it is lacking details, i.e. the user hasn't specified whether they know or not if the file has a file extension - and at this point in time they are unlikely to ever return to clarify the issue. It will never have an accepted answer and will always attract random answers...

Answer (score 2):

You may want to enable the displaying of file extensions in Explorer options, as described by 
[Show or hide file name extensions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-vista).

You may then remove the previously hidden .txt extension from your hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

Windows users are able to edit their host file directly from their PC.
Windows 7 or Vista

1. Browse to Start > All Programs > Accessories.
2. Right-click Notepad, and select "Run as administrator".
3. Click "Continue" on the UAC prompt.
4. Click File > Open.
5. Browse to `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc`.
6. Change the file filter drop-down box from Text Documents (*.txt) to All Files (*.*).
7. Select `hosts` and click Open.
8. Make the needed changes, as shown above, and close Notepad.
9. Save when prompted.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of this issue was actually discussed at a different StackExchange forum:

[same question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842750/why-is-windows-not-reading-my-hosts-file#:%7E:text=I%20ran%20into%20this%20problem,Windows%5CSystem32%5Cdrivers%5Cetc)

I tested with their steps as below. The steps solved my issue.

1. Copy the hosts file from C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc to
   somewhere    like Desktop
2. Remove the hosts file there
3. Copy the copied hosts file    back to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A link to another question or answer is not a good answer. Please cite the relevant parts of the linked asset, so your answer is standalone. The sole link might be a good comment under the question; as an answer it's not enough.

Comment: Quote one of the answers, probably the acepted answer, as well as including the link.